# why process 's stack size affect dumped core file size?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, stack, coredump

I don't understand why the set stack size affects the generated core file size(I read some doc, some says 'ulimit -s 0', this means no stack size, but the process works fine, so impossible with no stack room; and, 'ulimit -s SOMESIZE' set stack size of the process to SOMESIZE and it may result in core file truncated). To what I understand, it simply dumps the data of the virtual space of the process to the core file, and stack is part of this space. How does it work?

Comment: If you give a process more stack, why _wouldn't_ you expect that extra space to be part of a core dump?

Comment: that makes sense. so what I understand seems wrong. But the core is 'an image of process's memory at the time of termination.' so what's going on?

Comment: And stack is part of that memory.

Comment: I just recalled that the thread stack does affect the core size. so what you've mentioned I think it's right : give it more stack size & the core will get bigger.

Comment: @NPE can you up this question? I wanna figure it out, thx!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340293/what-exactly-is-and-what-does-a-core-dump-of-process-contain, which answers your question and provides a link for more detailed information.

Comment: still haven't explained why stack size is related to core file generating.('ulimit -s 0 set stack size to 0 & no core will be generated'). Thanks anyway.

Comment: sorry guys, I think I made a mistake that core size is set by 'ulimit -c SOMESIZE', not 'ulimit -s'. Problem solved. Thanks, all!

Comment: A core dump shows the memory that's allocated to the application. The stack is included in the core dump because the stack is part of the memory footprint of the application. What part of that explanation do you not understand?